# Git workflow for avoiding lots of merge noise in the logs

Tags: git, git-rerere

We currently have a workflow where `master` is the more long-term feature release branch and numbered branches like `3.0` are for releases coming up in the next week or so.

With the above example, we are pushing several last  minute changes to `3.0` that need to be merged into master. If we don't merge often, we'll wind up having `master` out of date without recent changes. If we merge as we go, we have logs full of merges from `3.0` to `master`.

The seemingly magical command [git-rerere](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rerere.html) seems to solve this problem, but only for local topic branches that you need to update. In other words, it would work if `3.0` was only on one person's machine and not public.

Is there a way to keep master up-to-date without all the ugly merge noise? Do I understand the use of rerere?

Comment: What about [rebasing](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing)?

Comment: `3.0` is a public branch, so rebasing would not be appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

`rerere` stands for "Reuse Recorded Resolutions". All it does is make your merges/rebases *easier* by remembering decisions you made in the past. It doesn't make them less noisy when they actually happen; what it does allow is going longer without doing a merge (because you can "pre-flight" the merge and not push the results).

Why is "having logs full of merges" an issue? You can use `git log --no-merges` to show the log without the merge commits.

Your options are basically this:

- Merge less often, which will make the merges, when you do need them, more difficult
- Merge more often and live with having merge commits in your logs
- Use rebasing, and deal with the issues that entails on a public repository
- Use cherry-picking, which means the branches won't share history

Comment: git log --no-merges can be very confusing because it hides the changes happening in the merge commits, especially when used with the -p flag. So in some situations it is a lot harder to work with a repo full of merge commits.